# NodeJs Application on Aws Ubuntu is running on ipv6

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, express

While running nodejs with express application on AWS ubuntu 16.04, it's running on tcp6 and due to this, i'm unable to access my application.
see below screenshot.
[image]

after adding IP address while creating server, it's giving below error.
[image]

I'm new to linux, so I do not know how to resolve it. please suggest.

Comment: did you open the port 1234 to public in AWS console?

Comment: Yes, I did, although i allowed all traffic for now. @iKoala

Comment: Actually i don't see any issue in your screenshot, you may want to provide more information before anyone can help you. Can you access the port and get data locally? You may want to try the port which is higher than 3000 because some system and firewall blocks all ports under 3000 by default (reserved for system).

Comment: It's a aws linux machine so only i can access it using putty from my machine. what other should i add so that you can understand the root cause.

Comment: What do you get when you access the port with local host?

Comment: how to do with aws linux? I'm trying to access my application on browser using the public ip gievn by aws. @iKoala

Comment: I think you have to learn `curl` and `wget` first. They are linux command.

Comment: you can use postman to access your app.

Comment: This is unrelated, but you probably shouldn't have MySQL/MariaDB/etc. listening on *all* interfaces (use the loopback interface instead).

Comment: @Dhirendra: I tried postman also, but same result.

Comment: @mscdex: I can access mysql database from my local machine using mysql work bench. As my screenshot is showing that port 3306 is on tcp and it accepts all ips (foreign address column).

Comment: @JitendraPancholi right, what I'm saying is that in general you *shouldn't* do that for security reasons. Unless you're restricting access to your database by IP in your server's firewall, *anyone* could connect to it (and possibly exploit vulnerabilities). If you need to connect to it remotely, tunnel your database connection over ssh instead. You'll also get the added benefit of hiding sensitive data transmitted over the database connection.

Comment: @mscdex: I understand your concern and I intentionally allowed all traffic for sometime. My problem is that I'm still unable to access my application even all traffic was allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly provide an IP to bind to in Node.js, otherwise it binds to IPv6. Documented here: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback

Somewhere in your code you should have something similar to this:

```
var app = express();
app.listen(1234);
```

Change it to:

```
var app = express();
app.listen(1234, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: @JitendraPancholi expanded answer with an example.

Comment: It is also not working for me. pm2 log says "Server starts on port: 8080
" but unable to access from outside.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi If you want to have it available from outside, then you need to replace 127.0.0.1 with the public v4 IP of your machine.

Comment: Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:1022
     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
     at Server._listen2 (net.js:1244:19)
     at listen (net.js:1293:10)
     at Server.listen (net.js:1389:5)
     at Function.app.listen (/home/ubuntu/consumerforum/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:556:24)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/consumerforum/app.js:127:5)
     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)

Comment: I tried with many other ports but same issue as shown in image and error log.

Comment: If you use ports below 1024 you need to be root.

Comment: I used all ports greater than 1024 like 5454.

Comment: I have put my code under "/home/ubuntu/consumerforum" directory in ubuntu 16.04 (AWS). Is it a problem?